# LINQ: сложить выборки

Tags: c#, linq

Прошу помочь мне в моей проблеме. Есть глоб. переменная `IEnumerable<FileClass> dublicates;`, где FileClass - мой класс с полями FileName, Size, FullPath. В эту переменную в методе, который вызывается несколько раз, записываются посредством Linq дубликаты файлов, примерно так:

```
void threadMethod(string path)
{
    if (!Stop)
        if (!Pause)
        {
            HashSet<FileClass> files = new HashSet<FileClass>();
            Stop = false;
            getallfiles(new DirectoryInfo(path), "*.*", files);
            if (dublicates!=null)
                dublicates.Concat(from rep in files group rep by rep.Name into g where g.Skip(1).Any() from rep in g select rep);//почему не происходит конкатенация?
            else dublicates = from rep in files group rep by rep.Name into g where g.Skip(1).Any() from rep in g select rep;                   
        }
        else
            wh.Set();
```

Этот метод, как я уже говорил, вызывается несколько раз. Мне нужно, чтобы результаты предыдущей выборки, хранимые в dublicates складывались с результатами текущей выборки. Вроде, я делаю Concat(), тем не менее, в dublicates сохраняется только последняя выборка, а не все.

Что не так и как побороть это?

Comment: если бы вы использовали синтаксис методов, а не синтаксис запросов, было бы проще([Сравнение синтаксиса запросов LINQ и синтаксиса методов](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb397947.aspx))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IEnumerable.Concat() не изменяет исходную переменную, поэтому результат надо присвоить:

```
dublicates = dublicates.Concat(...);
```